# Change directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell prompt's currently pointed to my C drive (`PS C:\>`).  How do I change directory to a folder on my Q (`PS Q:\>`) drive?

The folder name on my Q drive is "My Test Folder".

Comment: simple as this `cd -Path Q:/`

Comment: For those that need to change directory temporarily, e.g. in a script, there's [`Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/managing-current-location?view=powershell-7.3#saving-and-recalling-recent-locations-push-location-and-pop-location)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Unlike the CMD.EXE `CHDIR` or `CD` command, the PowerShell `Set-Location` cmdlet will change drive and directory, both. [`Get-Help Set-Location -Full`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-5.1) will get you more detailed information on `Set-Location`, but the basic usage would be

```
PS C:\> Set-Location -Path Q:\MyDir

PS Q:\MyDir>
```

By default in PowerShell, `CD` and `CHDIR` are alias for `Set-Location`.

([Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940935/asad) reminded me in the comments that if the path contains spaces, it must be enclosed in quotes.)

Comment: You have to enclose the path  in "" otherwise it will give you error. Command will look like this 
Set-Location "Q:\My Test Folder"

Comment: @Asad - Good point, and one that I should have included originally, though quoting is only necessary if the path contains spaces.

Comment: cmd.exe supports "cd /d e:\somedirectory" to also switch drives

Comment: The command works even without including the `-Path` parameter. Why? Is it always the case?

Comment: For the `Set-Location` cmdlet, since the most common use will be to use it like the old `CD` command, it makes sense for the "default" interpretation of an omitted parameter name to be to assume that it's the `-Path` parameter, and that's how the cmdlet was written. Other cmdlets may not default the same way. See the help information (linked in the answer) for a more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 42):

To go directly to that folder, you can use the `Set-Location` cmdlet or `cd` alias:

```
Set-Location "Q:\My Test Folder"
```

Answer (score 29):

Multiple posted answer here, but probably this can help who is newly using PowerShell

[image]

SO if any space is there in your directory path do not forgot to add double inverted commas "".

Comment: Single quotes will work as well, e.g., `Set-Location 'C:\Path With Spaces'`

Comment: `double inverted commas` ‍♂️

Answer (score 26):

You can simply type `Q:` and that should solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  Am I doing this correctly? 

PS C:\> Q:

Comment: Are you sure it's there? I guess if it's Q:/  drive that that is some sort of removable media, it is maybe something as simple as plugging it in.

Comment: The assumption is that the drive Q does in fact exist. If it does not, PowerShell will throw an error specifying that the drive does not exist.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad.

Comment: Love simple solutions :)

Answer (score 13):

```
Set-Location -Path 'Q:\MyDir'
```

In PowerShell `cd` = `Set-Location`

Comment: This must be one of the worlds best reason not to use Powershell.

Comment: Since aliases can be removed and redefined, I will _always_ use the expanded cmdlet in answers here - I can't assume that just because _I_ haven't removed or changed the `cd` alias, neither have you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `sl` command to be able to change directories. It is `Set-Location` but it is much shorter.

Example:

```
# Too verbose
Set-Location -Path C:\

# Just the right amount of characters to type
sl C:\
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why everyone talks about `Set-Location` and the fact that `cd` does not change drive and directory, in fact it actually does it (in powershell, not cmd), you just need to put quotes (single or double) around if there are spaces in folder name(s), also you can just type drive letter if you just want to go to its root:

[image]

Edit: now I started editing my PowerShell scripts with a "real" IDE I understood why everyone talks about `Set-Location`, `cd` is just an alias to it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your **Folder** inside a **Drive** contains spaces In Power Shell you can Simply Type the command then drive name and folder name within Single Quotes(''):

```
Set-Location -Path 'E:\FOLDER NAME'
```

[The Screenshot is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWCY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. On Powershell use Set-Location instead of cd.
2. Put path in quotes. Single quotes works for me.

> Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0'